# In F# how do I create a list of Async<unit> inside an async computation without mutable collection?

Tags: asynchronous, f#, producer-consumer

I have a small program using the producer/consumer pattern in F#. I want to start 1 producer, then 8 consumers, wait for the producer then wait for the consumers and end the program.

The code that sets this in motion is:

```
async {
    let! p = Async.StartChild producer
    let maxConcurrent = 8

    let consumers = List<Async<unit>>()

    for _ in 0 .. maxConcurrent - 1 do
        let! c = Async.StartChild consumer
        consumers.Add(c)

    do! p

    for i in 0 .. maxConcurrent - 1 do
        do! consumers[i]

}
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

While this works it feels wrong to use the mutable List from System.Collections.Generic instead of just F# list. But I cannot generate the list of Async needed using List. I have tried:

```
let consumers2 = List.init 8 (fun _ -> async {
        let! c = Async.StartChild consumer
        return c
})
```

But this now wraps it in async again, so it becomes a `list<async<async<unit>>>`, if it's instead return! then the app hangs (I'm guessing because I'm not awaiting the task that should start the Task instead awaiting also the task that awaits finalization)

[Full code is available here](https://github.com/peheje/LearningFSharp/blob/8cad47db8221027c4f5fbf9f9dd8898088394e5c/HackerNewsAsync/Program.fs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `Async.Parallel` will flatten the asyncs the way you want. The following seems to work correctly for me:

```ml
async {
    // I need the producer to run in it's own thread, not shared by the threadpool, because I rely on the consumer being allowed to block the thread with .Take
    let! p = Async.StartChild producer

    let maxConcurrent = 8
    let! consumers =
        List.init maxConcurrent (fun _ ->
            Async.StartChild consumer)
            |> Async.Parallel

    do! p

    for c in consumers do
        do! c
}
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks, just what I was after. I'm beginning to grok the Async package bit by bit.